# Django request.user.first_name not working in Safari

Tags: django, google-chrome, safari

the code {{ request.user.first_name }} used on a HTML page with Django works perfectly in Chrome. However, it is not working in Safari and just displays nothing.

Is there any alternative way of getting this or how can I fix this?

Not using Safari is not an option as people with Safari will use this web-app.

**EDIT:**

Minimum reusable example:

base.html

```html
<span class="user">
       {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
           Hello {{ request.user.first_name }},
           <a href="{% url "logout" %}">Logout</a>
       {% else %}
           <a href="{% url "login" %}">Log-in</a>
       {% endif %}
</span>
```

How it looks on Chrome:

[image]

Safari:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. I don't see how the browser would affect this in anyway, Django works on the _server side_...

Comment: I added pictures and the code snippet.

Comment: And does your user in Safari even _have_ a first name set? Again I repeat the browser should make no difference here (unless it is related to CSS, which it is not since "Hello" is rendered in both your images) as Django works on the server side. The example you provide will not reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is the same user in both cases. I am aware that there should be no difference between the two. As in the source code of the website (looking from the browser side) it once has the string "tom", but not in Safari. It is very difficult to provide a minimum reproducible example given Djangos structure. I would basically need to upload the entire project with the database.

Comment: Edit: I am an idiot, the website was still cached. On another note, how do I avoid getting the cached website instead of a new one.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are logged in with a different user in Safari, which this user doesn't have a value in first_name.

Please double check that your are logged in with a user have a valid first_name.

Comment: I am an idiot, the website was still cached.